# Mule-Throw error if the query parameter is not available

Tags: url, mule

I need to throw an exception if the query parameter say "**requestId**" is not present in request URL.

The URL looks like this: `my.server.com?requestId=123&age=26`

Here I'm logging the **requestId** in message property like this:

```
<message-properties-transformer scope="session" doc:name="Adding requestId">
    <add-message-property key="requestId" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.requestId]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
```

If the URL does not contain the requestId it will be null. But in this case I want to do a check for **requestId** whether it is present or not.
Then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all for putting your thoughts. Finally I got a simple way using groovy where I don't need to put any choice router or any expression filters. He is my code :

```
if(!message.getInboundProperty("http.query.params").find{ it.key == "requestId" }){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException('requestId does not exist');
}
```

Comment: you can use null safe

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement you can do the following :-

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.requestId)]">
                <logger message="query parameter exist" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="query parameter does not exist" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <!-- Throw your exception here -->
                <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
                  <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
                       throw new IllegalArgumentException('query parameter does not exist')
                   ]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:component>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
```

Here If **Query parameter exists** it will simply log in a logger and if **Query parameter does not exists** it will **throw** the exception you want ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried message filters?

```
    <message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true">
        <expression-filter
            expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.requestId != empty]" />
    </message-filter>
```

This will throw an FilterUnacceptedException when requestId is null, false, empty, zero or an empty collection.

You have to change the condition if the filter needs to accept zero.

---

Answer (score 0):

Use the below expression to check the query parameter availability in HTTP URL

```
#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.requestId)]
```

See below sample code that used choice router and based on query param availability it routes the control

```
 <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.requestId)]">
            <logger message="Query param available in request level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="Query param not available in request level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Comment: If the query param exits and doesn't have the value like `http://localhost:8081/test?requestId=&age=26` then the logger will print  `Query param available in request level` even though the value is not there

Comment: I agree with you Anirban. But the question is about checking query parameter existence in HTTP URL. But the one you suggested is more robust as it checks both scenarios. i.e empty query parameter and empty value for that query parameter. I will update my answer.